# SAS ARIMA modelling for 5 different variables

Tags: sas, forecasting

I am trying do a ARIMA model estimation for 5 different variables. The data consists of 16 months of Point of Sales. How do I approach this complicated ARIMA modelling?

Furthermore I would like to do:

- A simple moving average of each product group
- A Holt-Winters
  exponential smoothing model

Data is as follows with date and product groups:

```
 Date   Gloves  ShoeCovers  Socks   Warmers HeadWear

 apr-14 11015   3827        3465    1264    772
 maj-14 11087   2776        4378    1099    1423
 jun-14 7645    1432        4490    674     670
 jul-14 10083   7975        2577    1558    8501
 aug-14 13887   8577        6854    1305    15621
 sep-14 9186    5213        5244    1183    6784
 okt-14 7611    4279        4150    977     6191
 nov-14 6410    4033        2918    507     8276
 dec-14 4856    3552        3192    450     4810
 jan-15 17506   7274        3137    2216    3979
 feb-15 21518   5672        8848    1838    2321
 mar-15 17395   5200        5712    1604    2282
 apr-15 11405   4531        5185    1479    1888
 maj-15 11509   5690        4370    1145    2369
 jun-15 9945    2610        4884    882     1709
 jul-15 8707    5658        4570    1948    6255
```

Any skilled forecasters out there willing to help? Much appreciated!

Comment: Have you tried already `proc arima` and `proc forecast`? Could you share your code?

Comment: I have tried proc arima but not proc forecast. My real problem is just doing a simple moving average.

Comment: 16 observations is not enough for what is clearly seasonal data.  you should have at least 3x the seasonality.

Comment: ARIMA models are a generalization of moving average (MA) models. For instance, an ARIMA(0,0,1) model is a MA(1) model. You can use `proc arima` to build a moving average model.